# Program to Find a Line that Matches a Given End Point, Start Point, and Minimum Number of Turns

Tags: java, maze

I have written a program to solve mazes, and I am now writing a java program to create mazes (mazes are 32x32 png files in black and white). I need to be able to dictate to the program characteristics of the maze, while allowing some degree of randomness so that the maze, even when fed the same parameters, is not always the same. The way I'm approaching this is by first drawing the solution path, then embellishing the maze with extra paths to hide the solution. But I'm not sure how I should go about creating the solution path. This is one of those problems where I am stuck on square one, I'm thinking maybe I should assemble the path in segments, graphing a range from a several equations and then piecing them together, but how would I go about ensuring that the construction eventually makes it to the finish, without intersecting itself so many times that there are several ways to finish the maze? Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I used a variation of the algorithm described in the answer, which works by creating the solution path and then adding branches/false solutions. It is programmed to try to connect to the main path after the branch being made exceeds a set length; but the branches will only connect to one another for some reason, never to the path. I have included as much source code as reasonably possible without making this too confusing, I am of course willing to supply any other information.

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(width, height);
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    panel.zoom(8);

    List redsListX = new List();
    List redsListY = new List();
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < height-2; i = i + 2) {
        for (int j = 2; j < width-2; j = j + 2) {
            panel.setPixel(i, j, Color.RED);
            redsListX.add(Integer.toString(counter), j);
            redsListY.add(Integer.toString(counter), i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Grid frame set!");
    buildSolutionPath(bias1,bias2,panel);
    removeGreen(panel);
    System.out.println("Done building solution path!");

    addBranches(panel);
    System.out.println("Branches are done!");
    removeGreen(panel);
    System.out.println("Maze is completed!");
    panel.save("GeneratedMaze.png");

}
public static void buildSolutionPath(int bias1, int bias2, DrawingPanel panel){
    int posX = 2;
    int posY = 2;
    int posX2 = 2;
    int posY2 = 2;
    int posX3 = 2;
    int posY3 = 2;
    panel.setPixel(posX,posY,Color.GREEN);
    while(posX+posY!=64) {
        int rand = randomInt(bias1, bias2, 1, 4);
        if(rand==1 && panel.getRed(panel.getPixelRGB(posX, posY+2))==255){//what happens if rand equals a non-red tile?
            panel.setPixel(posX,posY+1,Color.GREEN);
            panel.setPixel(posX,posY+2,Color.GREEN);
            posY = posY+2;
        }
        if(rand==2 && panel.getRed(panel.getPixelRGB(posX+2, posY))==255){
            panel.setPixel(posX+1,posY,Color.GREEN);
            panel.setPixel(posX+2,posY,Color.GREEN);
            posX = posX+2;
        }
        if(rand==3 && panel.getRed(panel.getPixelRGB(posX, posY-2))==255){
            panel.setPixel(posX,posY-1,Color.GREEN);
            panel.setPixel(posX,posY-2,Color.GREEN);
            posY = posY-2;
        }
        if(rand==4 && panel.getRed(panel.getPixelRGB(posX-2, posY))==255){
            panel.setPixel(posX-1,posY,Color.GREEN);
            panel.setPixel(posX-2,posY,Color.GREEN);
            posX = posX-2;
        } else if(panel.getRed(panel.getPixelRGB(posX, posY+2))!=255 && panel.getRed(panel.getPixelRGB(posX+2, posY))!=255 && panel.getRed(panel.getPixelRGB(posX, posY-2))!=255 && panel.getRed(panel.getPixelRGB(posX-2, posY))!=255) {
            List bestGreen = findBestGreen(panel);
            posX = Integer.parseInt(bestGreen.getItem(0));
            posY = Integer.parseInt(bestGreen.getItem(1));
        }
    }
}
public static void addBranches(DrawingPanel panel) {
    for (int i = 2; i < height - 2; i = i + 2) {
        for (int j = 2; j < width - 2; j = j + 2) {
            if (panel.getRed(panel.getPixelRGB(j, i)) == 255 && panel.getGreen(panel.getPixelRGB(j, i)) != 255) {
                for (int counter = 0; counter < desiredBranchLength; counter++) {
                    int posX = j;
                    int posY = i;
                    int posX2 = j;
                    int posY2 = i;
                    int posX3 = j;
                    int posY3 = i;
                    int posX4 = j;
                    int posY4 = i;
                    int posX5 = j;
                    int posY5 = i;
                    int posX6 = j;
                    int posY6 = i;
                    int posX7 = j;
                    int posY7 = i;
                    int rand = randomInt(branchBias1, branchBias2, 1, 4);
                    panel.setPixel(j, i, Color.WHITE);
                    if (rand == 1 && panel.getRed(panel.getPixelRGB(posX, posY + 2)) == 255 && panel.getGreen(panel.getPixelRGB(posX, posY + 2)) != 255) {//what happens if rand equals a non-red tile?
                        panel.setPixel(posX, posY + 1, Color.WHITE);
                        posY7 = posY6;
                        posY6 = posY5;
                        posY5 = posY4;
                        posY4 = posY3;
                        posY3 = posY2;
                        posY2 = posY;
                        posY = posY + 2;
                    }
                    if (rand == 2 && panel.getRed(panel.getPixelRGB(posX + 2, posY)) == 255 && panel.getGreen(panel.getPixelRGB(posX + 2, posY)) != 255) {
                        panel.setPixel(posX + 1, posY, Color.WHITE);
                        posX7 = posX6;
                        posX6 = posX5;
                        posX5 = posX4;
                        posX4 = posX3;
                        posX3 = posX2;
                        posX2 = posX;
                        posX = posX + 2;
                    }
                    if (rand == 3 && panel.getRed(panel.getPixelRGB(posX, posY - 2)) == 255 && panel.getGreen(panel.getPixelRGB(posX, posY - 2)) != 255) {
                        panel.setPixel(posX, posY - 1, Color.WHITE);
                        posY7 = posY6;
                        posY6 = posY5;
                        posY5 = posY4;
                        posY4 = posY3;
                        posY3 = posY2;
                        posY2 = posY;
                        posY = posY - 2;
                    }
                    if (rand == 4 && panel.getRed(panel.getPixelRGB(posX - 2, posY)) == 255 && panel.getGreen(panel.getPixelRGB(posX - 2, posY)) != 255) {
                        panel.setPixel(posX - 1, posY, Color.WHITE);
                        posX7 = posX6;
                        posX6 = posX5;
                        posX5 = posX4;
                        posX4 = posX3;
                        posX3 = posX2;
                        posX2 = posX;
                        posX = posX - 2;
                    } else {//if no more reds to connect to, connect to white
                        if (connectWhite(posX,posY,panel)) {
                        } else if (connectWhite(posX7,posY7,panel)){
                        } else if (connectWhite(posX6,posY6,panel)){
                        } else if (connectWhite(posX5,posY5,panel)){
                        } else if (connectWhite(posX4,posY4,panel)){
                        } else if (connectWhite(posX3,posY3,panel)){
                        } else {
                            connectWhite(posX2,posY2,panel);
                            System.out.println("Branch failed to connect");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public static List findBestGreen(DrawingPanel panel){
    List bestGreen = new List();
    int bestGX = 2;
    int bestGY = 2;
    int bestGX2 = 2;
    int bestGY2 = 2;
    for (int i = 2; i < height-2; i = i + 2) {
        for (int j = 2; j < width-2; j = j + 2) {
            if(panel.getGreen(panel.getPixelRGB(j,i))==255) {
                bestGX2 = j;
                bestGY2 = i;
                int c = bestGX + bestGY;
                int c2 = bestGX2 + bestGY2;
                int score1 = ((bestGX*buildBias2X)+(bestGY*buildBias2Y));
                int score2 = ((bestGX2*buildBias2X)+(bestGY2*buildBias2Y));
                if (c2==c||c-c2<=4||c2-c<=4 && score2>score1){
                    bestGX = bestGX2;
                    bestGY = bestGY2;
                } else if(bestGX2+bestGY2>bestGX+bestGY){
                    bestGX = bestGX2;
                    bestGY = bestGY2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(bestGX+", "+bestGY);
    bestGreen.add(Integer.toString(bestGX));
    bestGreen.add(Integer.toString(bestGY));
    return bestGreen;
}
public static void removeGreen(DrawingPanel panel){
    for (int i = 2; i < height-2; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j < width-2; j++) {
            if(panel.getGreen(panel.getPixelRGB(j,i))==255){
                    panel.setPixel(j,i,Color.WHITE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
public static boolean connectWhite(int posX, int posY, DrawingPanel panel) {//attempts to connect the newly constructed branch with the main path
    if (panel.getGreen(panel.getPixelRGB(posX + 2, posY))==255 && panel.getRed(panel.getPixelRGB(posX+2,posY))!=255) {
        panel.setPixel(posX + 1, posY, Color.GREEN);
        panel.setPixel(posX + 2, posY, Color.GREEN);
        return true;
    } else if (panel.getGreen(panel.getPixelRGB(posX-2, posY))==255 && panel.getRed(panel.getPixelRGB(posX-2,posY))!=255) {
        panel.setPixel(posX - 1, posY, Color.GREEN);
        panel.setPixel(posX - 2, posY, Color.GREEN);
        return true;
    } else if (panel.getGreen(panel.getPixelRGB(posX, posY+2))==255 && panel.getRed(panel.getPixelRGB(posX,posY+2))!=255) {
        panel.setPixel(posX, posY + 1, Color.GREEN);
        panel.setPixel(posX, posY + 2, Color.GREEN);
        return true;
    } else if (panel.getGreen(panel.getPixelRGB(posX, posY-2))==255 && panel.getRed(panel.getPixelRGB(posX,posY-2))!=255) {
        panel.setPixel(posX, posY - 1, Color.GREEN);
        panel.setPixel(posX, posY - 2, Color.GREEN);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;//if return is false, it means there were no options for connecting the branch to the solution path
    }
}
```

[image: This is an example maze my program generated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many maze-generating algorithms out there but what I would recommend is the recursive backtracker algorithm. It is fast, efficient and easy to code. You can find more information on it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Recursive_backtracker) as well as some other algorithms. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Although I could use the algorithm you pointed out, and it doesn't look too hard at all, I need to be able to control certain aspects of the maze (such as the solution path), and the most I could really do with that one would be to create a bias in the initial formation to move from the start to finish, then add other branches, but I think that may leave a chance that the initial path would almost completely fill the map. I'll try it when I am home from work later though and comment how it works, it might be what I am looking for!

Comment: Ok, so I have a program working that lets me adjust enough variables to control the maze using a variant of this algorithm; the way it's working is by generating the solution path, then trying to build branches or false solutions in the unused space. But for some reason, although the branches are able to connect to each other, they NEVER connect to the solution path. At first I thought it was coincidence, but they are without fail only connected to each other.

Comment: The issue from above was caused by an implementation problem where when the points that the solution path intersected were used in it's construction, they were removed from the pool of usable points, thus making it impossible for branches to connect to them and therefore the solution path. Thanks for the answer!